# Javascript, How to store API response on client side with good effeciency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexeddb, react-apollo, workbox

I am newbie to **Javascript/Front end** ecosystem. During the last few days I started learning and building Apps using "React". The below is my stack

```
- React
- Apollo
- Spring Boot (backend) - Not much of significance to this question.
```

In my application I have a table which will have meta information between 100 to 2000 rows (close to 10 fields) which will be paginated. The meta data information will be ranging between **2 MB - 5 MB (Worst case)**.

### Question:

```
1. Would I be able to cache/store this data on the front end. 
2. Plan is to initially fetch 100 records and later make lazy loading calls.
3. I came across **IndexedDB** will this help me by any chance to cache in front end.
4. Will Apollo's caching can do better help for me.
5. Will it be better to explore options such as google's **"Workbox"** to have offline storage
```

### Why I need this on client side ?

```
   1. There is sorting of columns in fronted which is expected to be seamless.
   2. Search on multiple fields on the data. That is also expected to be seamless experience.
```

Feel free to ask more questions. Since this is one of the first question I am asking for front end I might have missed some glaring or striking  items which is essential to add value to this question.

What are my supported browsers?

```
 1. IE11
 2. Chrome 75+
 3. Firefox 70+
```

Comment: do you want to store that info for the session? for some days? If it is for the sessions i will use Redux. And also if you are going to work with tables i will recommend you to use react-table, you can make async pagination, filtering etc

Comment: Thank you for the info about react-tables. I will definitively take a look at the same. I don't want to save the info. When the user logs out  or do a page refresh the data should refresh back

Comment: You should check about redux if what you want is to fetch the info and store it each time the app is used. Redux might be a bit difficult at the beggining and even more if you are starting with React. Redux is a state manager where you can 'store' some info fetched from api or your own components